# Compare values between 2 array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have some problem to compare values from different array list
From this values, I need to compare and find the max n min

Here is my coding:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> S1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);  
    ArrayList<Integer> S2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);  
    ArrayList<Integer> S3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);  

    S1.add(49);S1.add(68);S1.add(91);S1.add(91);S1.add(12);  
    S2.add(85);S2.add(56);S2.add(62);S2.add(72);S2.add(94);  
    S3.add(76);S3.add(28);S3.add(52);S3.add(96);S3.add(70);
```

Example: i want to compare 49,85,76

Comment: Easily available on Google and if its Homework, post as such.

Comment: can you be more specific? you want to find the max element in the 3 arrays or to find for example which of them has the max element in index 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can add elements in a list easily by

```
 ArrayList<Integer> s1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);  
 s1.addAll(Arrays.asList(49, 68, 91, 12));
```

Furthermore, avoid using capitals for variable names, these are reserved for class names.

Now, to answer your question.  This can be done using a simple loop:

```
ArrayList<Integer> min = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);  
ArrayList<Integer> max = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);  

// ASSUMPTION: s1, s2 and s3 has the same length, or at least s1.length is the 
// shortest list
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
  max.add(Math.max(Math.max(s1.get(i), s2.get(i)), s3,get(i)));
  min.add(Math.min(Math.min(s1.get(i), s2.get(i)), s3,get(i)));
}
```

You'll end up with two arrays.  Each containing the minimum or maximum for a particular index value.  I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Or simply: `ArrayList<Integer> s1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(49, 68, 91, 91, 12))`

Comment: If list is never changed then `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(49, 68, 91, 91, 12);` is sufficient.

Comment: Good points on both cases.  I forgot about the constructor taking a list. Good suggestion, Shakedown.

Comment: Yes, i've tried it.Thank you.My mistake was i didn't use the '.get'

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can iterate over the three lists:

```
//TODO for the reader: check that the lists have the same length
for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++) {
  int s1 = S1.get(i);
  int s2 = S2.get(i);
  int s3 = S3.get(i);
  // compare s1, s2 and s3 here...
}
```

Since this looks like homework, I leave the comparison logic as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Build a new list (in your example list of first elements) and find min/max there, for example using Collections class.